# ServletException including path to jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servletexception

I have very complicated program to run. I don't expect anyone to analyze deeply but maybe somebody had similar issue or has a diagnosing tip. Application is being boot with Apache Tomcat. These is the stacktrace which I see browsing the page:

Exception:

```
org.apache.tiles.TilesException: ServletException including path '/resources/layout/Layout.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:614)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ScopeInterceptor.intercept(ScopeInterceptor.java:431)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

Root cause:

```
org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/resources/layout/Layout.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.wrapServletException(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:298)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:200)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:84)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ScopeInterceptor.intercept(ScopeInterceptor.java:431)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

It is very hard to diagnose form me what is really not working - but I expect something wrong on the side of Tomcat. Specified Layout.jsp file path seems to be good - but I cannot say if Tomcat sees the file. If I remove Layout.jsp I see the same error. On the other hand there is a file called tiles-config-ext.xml containing this:

```
<definition name="BOMainWindow" template="/resources/layout/Layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="something" />
    <put-attribute name="leftMenu" value="true" />
    <put-attribute name="rightBanner" value="something2" />
</definition>
```

When i change template to let's say Layout2.jsp  and create that file in proper location - I have different error - response 404. Even if I remove "Layout.jsp" from absolutely every file.

Comment: Put you `java` code for the Class/Interface/Enum or anything that is being used for "BOMainWindow" and/or "/resources/layout/Layout.jsp"..

And Yes.. the exception is from `org.apache.tiles` package.. but main problem lies definitely in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have found solution. I really don't know how the project could compile and build without any sign of lacking dependency for library. Here it is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/el-impl/2.2 and after adding it everything works.

Comment: Great you got it.. so now if you know the problem and solution very well, try to answer your own question as it is the main purpose of stackoverflow.com community to share the knowledge.. so that other people won't have to wander here n there.. :)